# Why am I getting a syntax error when trying to create a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a new table using the following:

```sql
CREATE TABLE onsale (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    name VARCHAR(255), 
    desc TEXT, 
    image_file VARCHAR(255)
);
```

However, I keep getting an error:

```
ERROR 1064: (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB version for the right syntax to use near: 'desc TEXT, image_file VARCHAR(255))' at line 1
```

I don't see what is wrong with my syntax. It seems okay to me (obviously).

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: My guess would be the `desc` keyword, which is used in `ORDER BY x DESC`. Is there a reason you're being terse, why not just `description`?

Comment: Try calling your column `Description`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name you used for your column `desc` is a reserved word.  You also need `primary key (id)`:

```
CREATE TABLE onsale (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(255),
  description TEXT,
  image_file VARCHAR(255),
  primary key (id)
);
```